# Compare Txt Files in Linux and Return Elements in File 1 for Elements in File 2

Tags: linux, shell, command

Here is the problem.

1. Host.txt file has only Hostnames as follows:

```
GVC-CH-ZRH-BRA-5H81-PELE
GVC-US-NYC-9TH-4C101-MEDROOM
GVC-US-NYC-9TH-4C101E-EXTRA
GVC-US-NYC-9TH-5E117-STUDIO54
```

2.HosandIp.txt has the Hostnames and Ip as follows (HostandIP has hostname,IP Address Note the Comma (,)):

```
GVC-CH-ZRH-BRA-5H81-PELE,170.16.75.101
GVC-US-NYC-9TH-4C101-MEDROOM,170.26.114.242
GVC-US-NYC-9TH-4C101E-EXTRA,170.26.108.224
GVC-US-NYC-9TH-5E117-STUDIO54,170.26.108.95
beta-gvc-personal-antoniop-526,170.26.107.180
beta-gvc-personal-antoniop-9100,170.26.106.206
beta-gvc-personal-antoniop-9100b,170.26.106.41
beta-gvc-personal-antoniop-office,170.26.107.192
```

I need to compare these two files and get only the IP Address in another text file called IPOnly.txt

1. IPOnly.txt has only the IP's common to both Host.txt and HostandIp.txt as follows:

```
170.16.75.101
170.26.114.242
170.26.108.224
170.26.108.95
```

It can be done in JAVA using HASH MAP. Is there a Linux Command to do this ? Please Help!

Comment: Pretty much under 10 lines of code in Java. Why don't you want to do it in Java?

Comment: doing this with simple shell tools is probably a bit of a stretch; Perl, Python, or Ruby would probably all be easier to use than `bash`, and I expect they'd all start faster than a JVM -- which one would work best for you? :)

Comment: @sarnold, standard shell tools are actually the easiest way to do it :-). `join` works directly on sorted files.

Answer (score 3):

```
sort Host.txt -o Host_sorted.txt
sort HosandIp.txt -o HosandIp_sorted.txt
join Host_sorted.txt HosandIp_sorted.txt -t, | cut -d, -f2
```

The input files must be sorted. The entries aren't quite sorted in the order desired by `join`, therefore I've included the calls to `sort` to do this. [Join man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/join/)

Comment: can also use process substitution to perform the sorts inline: `join <(sort Host.txt) <(sort HosandIp.txt) ...`

Comment: `join -t, -o2.2 <(sort -t, -k1,1n Host.txt) <(sort -t, -k1,1n HosandIp.txt)`

Comment: The performance of this is O(log(n)) versus the optimal solution being O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 0.02$ in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (HOST, '<Host.txt') || die;
open (HOSTANDIP, '<HostAndIp.txt') || die;

my %host2ip;
map { chomp; my ($h,$i) = split /,/; $host2ip{$h} = $i } (<HOSTANDIP>);

map { chomp; print "$host2ip{$_}\n" if exists($host2ip{$_}) } (<HOST>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
  NR == FNR {host[$1]++; next}
  ($1 in host) {print $2}
' Host.txt HostandIP.txt > IPOnly.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

My take using Python:

```
hosts_contents = open('Host.txt', 'r').read()
hosts_and_ips_contents = open('HosandIp.txt', 'r').read()
host_ips = dict(line.split(',') for line in hosts_and_ips_contents.splitlines())
hosts_wanted = set(hosts_contents.splitlines())
print '\n'.join(ip for host, ip in host_ips.iteritems() if host in hosts_wanted)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/^/\^/' -e 's/$/,/' Host.txt | egrep -f - HosandIp.txt | awk -F, '{print $2}' > IPOnly.txt`

Answer (score -1):

one-liner:

```
for line in $(cat host.txt); do sed -n s/$line',\(.*\)/\1/p' host-and-ip.txt ; done > ip-only.txt
```

in readable form:

```
for line in $(cat host.txt)
do
  sed -n s/$line',\(.*\)/\1/p' host-and-ip.txt 
done > ipOnly.txt
```

Comment: The performance of this is O(n^2) versus the optimal solution being O(n).

Comment: @AffluentOwl: I don't see the performance requirements in the question. Without concrete numbers of lines and so on, O(n²) needn't be slower than O(n).